# DXA Model Source Code

Tags: dxa, mvc

Recently I am using DXA and I want to customize some templates. There are source codes of views on presentation server.

Instead of creating new models, I want to do some changes on existing ones. Where can I find codes of those DXA models?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You failed to indicate which version of DXA you are using and if you are using .NET or Java, but here are the locations of the source code for the models of the DXA Core module. You find these in the DXA Modules repository on GitHub:

- .NET https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules/tree/master/webapp-net/Core/Models/Entity
- Java https://github.com/sdl/dxa-modules/tree/master/webapp-java/dxa-module-core/src/main/java/com/sdl/dxa/modules/core/model/entity

Comment: And I would recommend that you create a copy of the models you want to change and modify those rather than changing the core - as you may run into trouble whenever you decide to upgrade the DXA